# How To Set The Window Icon PySDL2

Tags: python, sdl-2, pysdl2

I want to set the window icon in PySDL2. I tried doing this

```py
self.icon = sdl2.ext.load_image("./assets/icon.png")
sdl2.SDL_SetWindowIcon(self.window, self.icon)
```

But since I'm using `sdl2.ext.Window` it doesn't work.

Any ideas on how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using sdl2.ext, I just imported sdl2 and sdl2.sdlimage.
Here is the code if anyone is wondering:

```
self.icon = "./icon.png"
image = sdl2.sdlimage.IMG_Load(self.icon.encode())
sdl2.SDL_SetWindowIcon(self.window, image)
sdl2.SDL_FreeSurface(image)
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be a limit to the quality of the image you place as an Icon.

window being sdl2.ext.Window

```
image = sdl2.ext.image.load_img(path_to_image)

sdl2.SDL_SetWindowIcon(
    window.window,
    image,
)
```

This code was taken from rubato a pysdl2 wrapper Game Engine for python.
Check it out here: https://rubato.app/.

Edit due to comments:

For your code it would look something like this:

```
self.icon = sdl2.ext.load_image("./assets/icon.png")
sdl2.SDL_SetWindowIcon(self.window.window, self.icon)
```

You only needed the actual object, stored at self.window.window.
self.window is a pointer?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31744613)